# Usage of JavaScript Development Tools components in RCP applications

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jsdt

I would like to know if it is possible to use components from the [JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) in my own Eclipse RCP application.

For instance, my application should be able to show a JS editor view so that the user can edit JS files within my application. Is this possible?

I don't want to write a JS editor from scratch.

How can I integrate the components I need to achieve this? The package `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt` doesn't even show when I try to add it as a dependency of my plugins...

Comment: What are you using as your Target Platform? All the Eclipse plugins you want to use will have to be in the target platform.

Comment: @greg-449 I have multiple locations set in my target platform, but the only one "public" is this one:  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150124073747/repository/. Not sure how I can add these new plugins in my target platform... Should I add a new location? Some guidance would be really appreciated :)

Comment: @greg-449 I was able to add the JavaScript Development Tools to my target platform. But the packages are still not appearing in the list of possible dependencies of my plugin. Should I do something else?

Comment: All the plugins in your target platform should appear in the 'required plug-ins' Add list.

Comment: @greg-449 In my "Run Configuration"? The packages aren't listed there either...